# Search Bar not working in Partner User

Tags: visualforce, partner-communities, global-search

Im using below code for custom search its working in Sandbox partner user.
But not working in Production's partner user it return "URL No Longer Exists".Please guide me.

```
<apex:page >
<form action="/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults" method="get">
<input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="str" size="100" maxlength="120"></input><input type="submit" value="Search" class="tfbutton"></input>
</form>
</apex:page>
```

Production:
[image]

Sandbox
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Are you sure this works in your partner sandbox? It doesn't work in
>   mine if I try to replicate. It does work when logged in as a 'normal'
>   user, though. I'll describe in my answer what I think the problem is,
>   but let me know if I'm on the wrong path..

A typical mistake when working with url's in communities is that the site prefix is not added to the url. You will see when being logged in as a partner that there is always an extra prefix between the typical SFDC url and the name of your page. E.g. (on sandbox):

```
https://sandboxname-mycompany.csXX.force.com/communityname/vfPage
```

In this case the prefix is 'communityname'.

Any relative url that you put in code is added to the first part of the current url:

```
https://sandboxname-mycompany.csXX.force.com/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults
```

This will work for 'normal' users, but not for community users. For those, you need:

```
https://sandboxname-mycompany.csXX.force.com/partnerCommunity/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults
```

In order to get this added, add the Site.Prefix to all urls that you want to use in a community (Note that it will be blank for normal users, to those will be able to use the same url).

So change your code to the following:

```
<apex:page >
    <form action="{!$Site.Prefix}/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults" method="get">
        <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="str" size="100" maxlength="120"></input><input type="submit" value="Search" class="tfbutton"></input>
    </form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Guy,
Thanks for reply, im used your code but  getting same error .Please see above my attached  images.

Comment: The partner url does not look ok to me yet. Can you show me the url of a 'normal' page in the partner community?